# web2py error: requires web2py 2.15.5 or newer

Tags: python-2.7, web2py, pythonanywhere, website-deployment

I'm trying to launch a web2py app I made using pythonanywhere. I packaged the app and then uploaded it using the admin site, but now when I go to the page it's supposed to be on I get the error "requires web2py 2.15.5 or newer"

What does this mean? And is there a way I can go about solving this without needing to rewrite my webapp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is coming from [these lines](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/14083907e50a394f5f0d5f21a6ab3512f1cc4f86/applications/welcome/models/db.py#L15) in the `db.py` model file of the scaffolding application:

```
if request.global_settings.web2py_version < "2.15.5":
    raise HTTP(500, "Requires web2py 2.15.5 or newer")
```

Presumably you are somehow using the scaffolding application from web2py 2.15.5+ with an earlier version of web2py. You can try removing those lines, and everything *may* work, but there may be some code in the scaffolding app that relies on features available only in version 2.15.5 or later.

Alternatively, use the scaffolding app that comes with you installed version of web2py, or upgrade web2py to the latest version.